# Django Reverse One-To-One Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Im using the DjangoBB forum system, and Im trying to add some features to it.

We have a few different models we are working with here. I will include the important parts.

User (from django.contrib.auth.models){No important code to show}

Profile and Post (from djangobb_forum.models):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField(User, related_name='forum_profile', verbose_name=_('User'))
    //AutoOneToOne is a slight, irrelevant modification of OneToOne, just pretend that its OneToOne for these purposes
    ...
    allowed_to_post = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, default=0)

class Post(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts', verbose_name=_('Topic'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts', verbose_name=_('User'))
```

I need to create a view that will display all of the posts where the profile associated with the user associated with the post, has a allowed_to_post value of less than 5. Ive tried the following two methods:

```
d_posts = Post.objects.filter(user__profile__allowed_to_post__lt = 5)
```

and

```
d_users = User.objects.filter(profile__allowed_to_post__lt = 5)
d_posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in=d_users)
```

Both give the message:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'profile' into field. Choices are: _message_set, ban_users, date_joined, email, first_name, forum, forum_profile, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, post, posts, posttracking, received_messages, registrationprofile, reported_by, reputations_from, reputations_to, sent_messages, subscriptions, topic, user_permissions, userassociation, username, zapped_by
```

I dont understand why it doesnt work, because even with OneToOne fields, there should be reverse associations.

Let me know if you do need to see more of the code.

Comment: Isn't the `related_name='forum_profile'` going to change the related name from `user__profile...` to `user__forum_profile...`?  Isn't that the point of the related name?

Comment: You just solved it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5):

The `related_name='forum_profile'` changes the related name from `user__profile...` to `user__forum_profile...`

That's the point of the related name attribute of a foreign key or one-to-one key field.